# is it possible to use more than 4gb ram in a x86 Win XP box IF I give all the extra ram to a virtual pc?

Tags: virtual-machines

I'm thinking the short answer here is NO. The memory is simply inaddressible past the 3.5gb mark from what I understand. But my motherboard has hardware assisted virtualization so I am wondering if I can just tell my virtual pc to steal its ram from the unused chunk of address space instead of the Host OS?

I wanted to ask here before I wasted money buying some ram for a machine that has more and more virtual stuff to run these days.

I'm asking more specifically for MS Virtual PC 2007 but I have VMWare Workstation available as well if it's a matter of one can do it but the other guy can't.

I appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only memory you can assign to a VM running under Windows is what Windows itself has access to, regardless of what virtualisation software you use.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You would need to move to a 64-bit Windows to use more than 4GB of RAM. And since the host OS doesn't see it, neither can your Virtual guests.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, Windows XP is [limited to 4GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487508.aspx):

> The maximum amount of memory that can be supported on Windows XP Professional and Windows Server 2003 is also 4 GB.

Comment: Microsoft says they support it, but in most cases I never got XP or w2k3 32bit to use more then 3gigs (Meaning, to effectively use it, upgrade)